# Use cases for -U

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Some C compilers provide -D to define a macro on the command line and -U to undefine one (built-in or defined with -D).

I have used -D, but I'm curious about -U. What are the cases where it's useful in practice?

Comment: I've hardly ever used `-U` in (ouch) 30 years of C programming.  There are very few use cases for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one use case (I'm sure there are others):

Where your C compiler is being called from another application that *generates the source* for the C compiler, you won't easily get access to the source to modify it by hand (although most such compilers have a "keep C" option, editing generated code by hand is something to avoid). Usually the first compiler will have a bunch of options to set, and also let you pass further options to the C compiler yourself in an "options for the C compiler" argument (for instance, it might do this to let you control C compiler optimisation levels without assuming that the compiler is GCC). And sometimes the options for how to ultimately compile the generated code are controlled by macros built into the C output: since the output doesn't exist at the time you're entering command line options, `-U` and `-D` may be the only way to set those flags.

Real-world example: [Gambit-C](http://dynamo.iro.umontreal.ca/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) defaults to the option to output one massive C function instead of many separate ones, which (according to the docs) makes it easier for a C compiler to optimise the final code. It actually outputs the same C either way, toggling the behaviour with the `__SINGLE_HOST` macro. But compiling one huge function can take forever (or just fail) on an older machine, so there needs to be a way to turn this behaviour off. `-U__SINGLE_HOST` as one of the passed-through arguments to the C compiler can make it possible to actually compile Gambit projects on older computers while still enjoying some level of optimisation.

In this case the behaviour of `__SINGLE_HOST` could have been handled by the Gambit compiler instead, but while not strictly necessary, it gives more freedom to the person designing the first compiler. Which is always good.

The more generalised version of this answer would be that `-U` is useful any time your build system passes a bunch of `-D` arguments, and you don't want all of them; it can un-set default definitions after the system sets them.

Answer (score 1):

I can only think of two cases where this can be useful:

1. If you have a `#ifdef MY_MACRO` or `#ifndef MY_MACRO` in your code, and MY_MACRO is defined (probably built-in, otherwise you could just delete it), and you want to compile without this macro (to change the behaviour of `#ifdef`)
2. Or if you want to redefine a macro with a different definition you "should" undefine it first (I write should, because the compiler complains if you doesn't, but everything works fine anyway)